# Require that a pointer has two base classes simultaneously

Tags: c++, templates

I have a situation like this.

```
struct ViewModel {...};
struct Movable : virtual ViewModel {...};
struct Selectable : virtual ViewModel {...};
```

(These are all "interface" classes with no data members)

There are many sub-interfaces similar to `Movable` and `Selectable`, describing different features a `ViewModel` may or may not have, with corresponding methods to work with these features.  The idea is that a `ViewModel` will implement a bunch of these.

Now I am implementing a feature which needs a `ViewModel` which is both `Movable` and `Selectable`.  Of course I could

```
struct MoveSelectable : virtual Movable, virtual Selectable {};
```

And require that `MoveSelectable` be implemented as well, but that is too much.  Is it possible to make a combinator so that I could do this without having to introduce a new class, so that the view model implementor needn't need to know about this combination?  For example,

```
void selectAndMove(intersection<Movable, Selectable>* viewModel) {...}
```

Comment: There are pure virtual **functions**, but not "pure virtual classes".

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm aware of the precise terminology, but I trusted my readers were smart enough to know what I meant.

Comment: Sound engineering means not guessing at the intended meaning of sloppy terminology.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe using SFINAE

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Movable, T>
              && std::is_base_of_v<Selectable, T>> selectAndMove (T * vm)
 { ... }
```

This way you have a template function that accept every template type `T` pointer **but** is enabled only if `T` derive from `Moveable` **and** `Selectable`.